# Как подключится к нескольким схемам postgreSql в Laravel

Tags: postgresql, laravel-5.7

Есть готовая база данных на PostgreSql. В ней имеются 4 схемы, но в конфигах в Laravel я могу указать лишь одну, так вот, как подключатся к остальным схемам?